# Gets RefrenceErrors: "Property 'Ionicons' doesn't exist"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

So im trying to add a bottom navbar in my ReactNative project. But everytime I try to run the project i get an error.

This is the message i get:
[image: The message i get is:]

I also get a warning saying: Bottom Tab Navigator: 'tabBarOptions' is deprecated. Migrate the options to 'screenOptions' instead.

I have tried to edit the edit the Ionicons code, by doing this:

```
return <IonIcon icon={iconName.props}></IonIcon>;
```

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, TextInput, ScrollView, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';



// Screens
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/SettingsScreen.js';

//Screen names
const homeName = "Home";
const detailsName = "Details";
const settingsName = "Settings";

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MainContainer() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={homeName}
        screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
            let iconName;
            let rn = route.name;

            if (rn === homeName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'home' : 'home-outline';

            } else if (rn === detailsName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'list' : 'list-outline';

            } else if (rn === settingsName) {
              iconName = focused ? 'settings' : 'settings-outline';
            }

            // You can return any component that you like here!
            return <Ionicons name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
          },
        })}
        tabBarOptions={{
          "tabBarActiveTintColor": "tomato",
          "tabBarInactiveTintColor": "grey",
          "tabBarLabelStyle": {
            "paddingBottom": 10,
            "fontSize": 10
          },
          "tabBarStyle": [
            {
              "display": "flex"
            },
            null
          ]
        }}>

        <Tab.Screen name={homeName} component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={detailsName} component={DetailsScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name={settingsName} component={SettingsScreen} />

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MainContainer;
```

Comment: You need to import you IonIcons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using expo? If so, you need to import.

```
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
```

Comment: and if he is using React Native? Is it the same?

Comment: I believe if you're using React Native but not expo, it would be: import Icon from 'react-native-ionicons' but you would not get the error that was mentioned since the react native import is called "Icon" and the error mentioned "Ionicons" specifically.